# ElasticSearch aggregation query customized field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am just wondering for a aggregation query in ES, is that possible to utilize the returned bucket for your own purpose. For example if I have response result like this:

```
        {
           "key": "test",
           "doc_count": 2000,
           "child": {
              "value": 1000
           }
        }
```

And I want to get the ratio of doc_count and value, so I am looking for a way to generate another field/aggregation to do the math of those two fields, like this:

```
        {
           "key": "test",
           "doc_count": 2000,
           "child": {
              "value": 1000
           },
           "ratio" : 2
        }
```

or

```
        {
           "key": "test",
           "doc_count": 1997,
           "child": {
              "value": 817
           },
           "buckets": [
              {
               "key": "ratio",
               "value": 2
              }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: I never used, but reference shows that you can have a scripted aggregation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) , however I don't think it is a good idea. Why are you trying to delegating that to ES?

Comment: I saw that documentation, but I don't think that's gonna work for "doc_count" and "value" fields. I am not going to do that, as you said that is not a good idea, just wondering if this feature is supported :)

Comment: Best think you will do! ES is great but don't push it. =)